# IF between time in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, function, datetime, hana

```
SELECT SERIES_ROUND(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TIME,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),'INTERVAL 30 MINUTE') as TIME
```

returns a result like "Mon Nov 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"

what i need is to return shift name

```
if time between 08:00:00 and 16:30:00 return SHIFT A
if time between 16:30:00 and 00:15:00 return SHIFT B
if time between 00:15:00 and 08:00:00 return SHIFT C
```

any help appreciated

Comment: You won't be able to check for 00:15 if you are rounding on 30 minutes, will you?

Comment: Hi johannis8. I have  no prob changing to 15min interval but im new to sql and dont know how to use if functions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TIME,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS TIME) BETWEEN TO_TIME ('08:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIME ('16:30:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN 'Shift A'
   WHEN CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_TIME,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS TIME) BETWEEN TO_TIME ('00:15:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIME ('08:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN 'Shift C'
   ELSE 'Shift B' END
```

Answer (score 1):

This reads a bit like a query that should process the clock-in times of workers or something similar.

Therefore I used *clock_ins* as the name for the timestamped events in my example code.

To make this work correctly, it helps to make the different computations and data type conversions step by step:

```
WITH clock_ins AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, to_timestamp('20200101080012', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) AS DATE_TIME FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS ID,  to_timestamp('20200101043135', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) AS DATE_TIME FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 AS ID, to_timestamp('20200101120056', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) AS DATE_TIME FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 AS ID, to_timestamp('20200101170012', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) AS DATE_TIME FROM DUMMY
),
clock_ins_rounded AS (
    SELECT
        ID
        , SERIES_ROUND(DATE_TIME,'INTERVAL 30 MINUTE') AS clock_in
        , to_time(SERIES_ROUND(DATE_TIME,'INTERVAL 30 MINUTE')) AS clock_in_time
    FROM    
        CLOCK_INS)
SELECT
      id
    , CLOCK_IN
    , clock_in_time 
    , CASE
        WHEN clock_in_time BETWEEN to_time('08:00:00') AND to_time('16:30:00') THEN 
            'SHIFT A'
        WHEN (   clock_in_time >= to_time('16:30:00') 
              OR clock_in_time <= to_time('00:15:00')) THEN 
            'SHIFT B'
        WHEN clock_in_time BETWEEN to_time('00:15:00') AND to_time('08:00:00') THEN 
            'SHIFT C'        
        ELSE 
            'NO SHIFT'
      END AS SHIFT
FROM 
    clock_ins_rounded;


ID|CLOCK_IN           |CLOCK_IN_TIME|SHIFT  |
--|-------------------|-------------|-------|
 1|2020-01-01 08:00:00|     08:00:00|SHIFT A|
 2|2020-01-01 04:30:00|     04:30:00|SHIFT C|
 3|2020-01-01 12:00:00|     12:00:00|SHIFT A|
 4|2020-01-01 17:00:00|     17:00:00|SHIFT B|
```

The first WITH-clause `CLOCK_INS` generates the test data and includes at least one case for every rule the OP mentioned.

The second WITH-clause `CLOCK_INS_ROUNDED` performs the "rounding" to the 30 minutes intervals via the `SERIES_ROUND` function (good choice!). It also takes the result from this rounding and creates a *time of day* version from it via the `TO_TIME()` function. This column is then made available as `CLOCK_IN_TIME`.

The final and main `SELECT` clause projects the computed `CLOCK_IN` timestamp, the `CLOCK_IN_TIME` column, and also the assigned shifts.

The shifts are assigned via a `CASE` statement. To make this work correctly it is important to use `TIME` data types for the comparisons. Leaving out the `TO_TIME( )` conversion for each of the conditions would lead to *implicit type conversion* and the comparison would be calculated as **string comparisons** which is **NOT** what you want for this use case.

The other important bit to notice is the rule for **SHIFT B**. This rule describes an *interval* between a time before and a time after midnight. As we are dealing with *instants* of time (actually not even that - it's just *time of day* data we use) here and not with *intervals* the `BETWEEN` comparison would not work correctly for the case of `BETWEEN 16:30 AND 00:15`.
Therefore, we need to take care of this in the code and translate this condition to `LARGER (LATER) THAN 16:30` **OR** `SMALLER (EARLIER) THAN 00:15`.

Finally, it is a good idea to include an *others* branch in `CASE` statements, so that it is easy to detect data that is not handled by any rule or when rules are not "catching" data that they should have caught.

In summary, these are the main points to consider for this requirement:

- implement one computation at a time and avoid overly nested expressions (to make the code easier to be read and understood)
- use an appropriate data type for the comparison semantic (e.g. use a `TIME` data type when using time comparisons like "earlier" or "later). This includes both the data to be processed as well as the comparison data in the code.
- when dealing with time-related data types, make sure to understand the differences between date-time, intervals, and time-of-day data
- when using `CASE` statements, include an *others* case for data that is not handled by the other rules